# Css oval box shadow too blurry

Tags: html, css

i have a school project where i need to replicate a website.
i want to add the shadow effect under text in a stretched oval way but i cant figure out how to do this prefectly, i just end up with a blurry rectangle.

this is what i have at the moment[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEIXR.png)

and this is what it is supposed to look like [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTmS4.png)

This is the code that i have (that creates the blurry rectangle

```
box-shadow: 0 50px 20px -8px #000000;
```

can anyone help me on how to make the shadow that i have now into the shadow that it is supposed to be? (2nd picture)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried to do it using `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a pseudo-element, translate and rotate it through `transform`, and add a `filter: blur` to it. Do note eventual compatibility issues.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem;
}

button::after {
  content: '';

  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 200%) rotateX(70deg);
  
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```